# as.numeric creates hanging decimal

Tags: r

Curious whats causing this behavior. Reading in an excel file with numbers stored as text. When I convert to numeric, integers get a decimal point added (i.e. 153  becomes 153.) No 0, nothing, just a hanging decimal. Any idea on how to correct this?

```
    structure(list(`Nest ID` = c("21Lk", "21Lk", "21Lk", "21Lk", 
"A-Frye"), `Clutch size` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), `hatch size` = c("4", "4", "4", 
"4", "7"), `hatch date` = c("146", "146", "146", "146", "153"
), Date = c("149", "167", "188", "247", "161"), Time = c("900", 
"900", "1200", "1224", "1538"), Cygnets = c("4", "3", NA, NA, 
"7"), detection = c("1", "1", "0", "0", "1"), `Age when found (days)` = 
c("3", 
"3", "3", "3", "8"), `Age at time of observation (days)` = c("3", 
"21", "42", "101", "8"), `prob of complete brood loss` = c("0.5", 
"0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.1"), `Predator fish present (1 likely, 2 unknown, 0 
unlikely)` = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1"), `Wetland Area (NWI) (ha)` = c("109.4938966", 
"109.4938966", "109.4938966", "109.4938966", "34.923899399999996"
), Notes = c(NA, NA, "unsure, could have been in the deep veg", 
"unsure, could have been in the deep veg", NA)), .Names = c("Nest ID", 
"Clutch size", "hatch size", "hatch date", "Date", "Time", "Cygnets", 
"detection", "Age when found (days)", "Age at time of observation (days)", 
"prob of complete brood loss", "Predator fish present (1 likely, 2 unknown, 
0 unlikely)", 
"Wetland Area (NWI) (ha)", "Notes"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the code used to convert/cleanup

```
library(tidyverse)

test.2<-test%>%
    rename(NestID=`Nest ID`,
            CS=`Clutch size`,
            HS=`hatch size`,
            HD=`hatch date`,
            DOY=Date,
            Age.firstobs=`Age when found (days)`,
            Age.current=`Age at time of observation (days)`,
            is.broodloss=`prob of complete brood loss`,
            pred.fish=`Predator fish present (1 likely, 2 unknown, 0 unlikely)`,
            WA=`Wetland Area (NWI) (ha)`)%>%
    mutate_at(vars(CS:DOY,Cygnets,Age.firstobs,Age.current,pred.fish),funs(as.numeric))%>%
    mutate_at(vars(detection,is.broodloss,WA),funs(as.numeric))
```

Comment: Please check your `digits` setting in option.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why this occured? I've never had this issue before.

Comment: I checked and it's 7

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data please? I can't replicate a situation where a string `153` becomes `153.` when converted to numeric.

Comment: edited: added snippet of data and the code I've been using

Comment: It might be printing behavior of tibbles in the newer versions of the `tibble` packag. There have been some updates recently. Do you see the same thing if you do `print.data.frame(head(test.2))`? Maybe also share your `sessionInfo()` so we can see the versions of attached packages.

Comment: D'oh!  It must be one of those updates. I'm on a new computer and had to reinstall some libraries. Probably why I've never seen it before Thanks! tibble is 1.4.2